# Use crontab to automate R script

Tags: r, shell, cron, rstudio-server

I am attempting to automate a R script using Rstudio Server on ec2 machine.

The R script is working without errors. I then navigated to the terminal on RStudio Sever and attempted to run the R script using the command - Rscript "Rfilename" and it works.

At this point I created a shell script and placed the command above for running the R script in there. This shell command is also running fine - sh "shellfilename"

But when I try to schedule this shell command using crontab, it does not produce any result. I am using the following cron entry :

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/sh ./shellfilename.sh
```

I am using cron for the first time and need help debug what is going wrong. My intuition is that there is there is difference in the environments used by the command when I run it on terminal and when I use the same in crontab. In case it is relevant information - am doing all of this on a user account created for myself on this machine so would differ from admin account.

Can someone help resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: @joran - I've added that detail to the post. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue arose due to relative paths used in the script for importing files and objects. Changing this to absolute path resolved the described issue.